# Defines jQuery function parameter as string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask a simple question but just searched around the web and I can't get the answer.

> function item(barcode)

When the barcode start from zero, it will converted to a int and delete the first zero number, e.g. 0123456, the barcode will be changed into 123456 in the function. How to fix it?

Thank you before.. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Please provide the code of the function `item`

Comment: It just fixed by Samich's answer. Thanks all.

Comment: supply your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the params when you passing it to the function: Here is examples:

```
item(000001) // this will trim your value because it's numeric value and input param will be numeric

item('000001') or item("000001") // in this case you will get full string with leading zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this ?

```
function item(barcode)
{
   if (barcode.charAt(0) == 0)
   {
       barcode = parseInt(barcode);
   }

   return barcode;
}
```